# ASP Cache doesn't add items when key dependency is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching

I'm writing a wrapper around `System.Web.Caching.Cache`. Add method:

```
public void Add(string key, object data, IEnumerable<string> dependency)
{
        var toInsert = dependency.Where(i => i != null && key != i).ToArray();
        Cache.Add(key
            , data
            ,   toInsert.Any() 
                ? new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(null, toInsert) 
                : null
            , System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration
            , TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
            , System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Cache[key]);
}
```

The problem is when `CacheDependency` is not null, item is not added to cache.

But this method works:

```
public void Add(string key, object data, IEnumerable<string> dependency)
{
    var toInsert = dependency.Where(i => i != null && key != i).ToArray();
    Cache.
    Cache.Add(key
        , data
        , null
        , System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration
        , TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
        , System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Cache[key]);
}
```

Item is added and printed to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item is not added to cache if at least one of keys in dependency is not present in cache at insert moment.

Answer (score 0):

The way you construct the `CacheDependency` looks a bit odd. You've set the path array to be null. Ref [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/818kahch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Can you try changing this

```
new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(null, toInsert)
```

to

```
new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(new [], toInsert)
```

Comment: In example in doc you referred null is used as first parameter. Passing empty array as first parameter didn't help.

Comment: Hmm - what's the value of dependency passed in from your calling function?

Comment: I've got an idea. Maybe the issue is that these keys aren't presented in cache at the moment. I'll check this out.